# What is a smasher?

Tags: meaning

Could anyone clear up for me the meaning of the word I found in *Red Headed League* by Conan Doyle?

> John Clay, the murderer, thief, **smasher**, and forger.

So what is "smasher" in this case?

1. Similar to a forger who who makes fake money.
2. Burglars who smash windows into someone's house, or smash glass showcases at the jewelry store.

Comment: A forger makes fake documents in general, not just fake money. Which is why Doyle wrote *smasher, and forger*.

Comment: I'd see **Smasher** as different to **Counterfeiter** - one who passes the coins into circulation as opposed to one who creates the bad coins in the first place.

Answer (score 23):

A smasher is a person who puts counterfeit coins into circulation. Here's the relevant definition from [A Dictionary of Archaisms and Provincialisms](https://books.google.com/books?id=9wCMSgS6WkcC&pg=PA761&dq="a+passer+of+counterfeit+coin.".) (1855):

> **Smasher**
>   a passer of counterfeit coin.

(This definition was in earlier sources too; the Oxford English Dictionary cites it as being in the 1795 edition of *A new dictionary of all the cant and flash languages, both ancient and modern*.)

Answer (score 7):

From [Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/4zbdddq)

***Smasher*** (UK Und.):

> ***(also bit(t) smasher)*** one who makes or passes counterfeit money.
>
> ***1796   [UK]*** *Proceedings Old Bailey 6 Apr. 443/2:* Q. Were you not taken up on suspicion of being a smasher? – A. I do not know the meaning of the word. Q. Upon your oath, do not you go about with a bag, and cry ‘any bad shillings’? – A. No. [...] Q. You would be surprized, if I were to tell you a smasher means a putter off of bad money?

The term derives from the noun [smasher](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/6gijnva#sn1) meaning

> (UK Und.) ***counterfeit money*** [? it smashes the hopes of those who use it].1790.

Comment: I would've assumed the origin would be the process used to produce such fake coins - you have a negative mold of the coin you want to fake and you literally SMASH it onto some cheap material to make an impression that looks like a real coin.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I agree, but that’s what Mr. Green suggests.